# BUTTON NOT PRESSING IN FLUTTER

Tags: button

My elevated button does not press when positioned where it should be. however, it presses when positioned in other parts of the screen.
the button is meant to navigate from one screeen to to another. please assist. thanks.

Navigating between pages

Comment: Sure, you button is meant to do that, but we'd like to see the relevant code. Please edit your question.